# Bot readout for who used a command

Tags: discord.js

Wanting to have a readout channel for my bot to keep track of what happens, just like a second console log. Want to be able to have it read out in the message the username of the person who used the command. Any ideas? Also, in a similar note, is there a way to copy the console readout and possibly just paste that instead?

```
var Scraper = require('images-scraper');
const google = new Scraper({
    puppeteer: {
      headless: true
    },
  })

module.exports = {
    name: 'image',
    description: 'Google image scraper',
    async execute(message, args){
      const readout = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'bot-readout');
        const image_query = args.join(' ');
        if(!image_query) return message.channel.send('Please enter a valid image search.');
        const image_results = await google.scrape(image_query, 1);
        message.channel.send(image_results[0].url);
        readout.send('Image sent');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want
**message.author.username** (It gives username who sent the message)
or **message.member** (it gives user as a guildmember)

Comment: Problem is when I add that into my send command: readout.send('Image sent to ${message.author.username}');          All it does is put exactly what I typed, wouldn't turn it into a function.

Answer (score 0):

Just access the `author` property of the message object and include it via a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) into the message:

```
readout.send(`Image sent to ${message.author.username}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing an embed system in a separate channel on my discord.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'suggestionlog',
    description: 'logs suggestion',
    execute(message){
        const readout = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'bot-readout');

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('FADF2E')
        .setTitle(message.channel.name)
        .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setDescription(message);
        readout.send(embed)
        .catch((err)=>{
            throw err;
        });
    }
}
```